# Select date from date picker in yatra.Com

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Hi I am new to python and Selenium. 
I am learning it out of interest. My question is
I want to select departure date and arrival date in below site. 
https://www.yatra.com/
I need the code in python using selenium,   can any one please help me with this. 
You can use any other library if required.

Thanks for assistance.

Comment: did you try anything? please post your code tries?

Answer (score 0):

1. Come up with a relevant [locator strategy](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#locator-strategies) to identify the date pickers and dates. Use the associated [find_element](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element) function implementation
2. Click "origin" datepicker
3. Use [Explicit Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) to wait until the available dates list appears (you need to do it as the dates list as clicking on the datepicker doesn't trigger page reload and if you will attempt to click at the desired date immediately - the date will be not there yet, check out [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/) for more details)
4. Choose desired date (or go for a [random](https://pynative.com/python-random-choice/) one)
5. Click the desired date
6. Again use Explicit Wait for the dates list to disappear
7. Repeat steps 2-6 for the "destination" datepicker

Example code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
import random

driver = webdriver.Chrome("c:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe")  
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.yatra.com')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

departure = wait.until(
    expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='flight_origin_date']"))).click()

wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//td[@data-date]")))
dates = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@data-date]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()",random.choice(dates))
wait.until(expected_conditions.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//td[@data-date]")))
destination = wait.until(
    expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='flight_destination_date']"))).click()

wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//td[@data-date]")))
dates = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@data-date]")
random.choice(dates).click()
wait.until(expected_conditions.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//td[@data-date]")))

driver.quit()
```

The above code assumes [Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/) browser and [ChromeDriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org), however you can use different browser of your choice.